# SOQL Count query on large number of records

Tags: soql, governorlimits, count

I am attempting to run a count query in workbench(and dev console).  I am simply trying to count the number of records within the object(with 2 where statements). My estimation is that there is ~28 million records in this object. I keep getting this error:

> A fatal error occurred. Contact your administrator and provide the following error id: [future_get-X-XXXXXXXXXXXX].

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a better way to do this? Is there a reason this is failing?

Comment: Do you receive any different behavior or other messages if you execute the query otherwise (e.g., Query Editor, or even Anonymous Apex)?